# GWT charts: All charts are not showing sometimes

Tags: gwt, charts

I have 4 charts (1 PieChart, 1 LineChart, and 2 ScatterChart's) that I need to load at once. Below is how my code looks like. I basically followed what is in [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-charts/). My problem is that sometimes, all the charts show, but sometimes, only some show and the rest just show blank space. I was thinking that maybe it's because of the long load time required to retrieve my data needed to be visualized on charts. There might be some race conditions somewhere and I don't know how to figure it out. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

```
    public interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<ReportsHandlers>  {
        FlowPanel getPageChartWrap();
        FlowPanel getLikeScatterChartProductWrap();

        DateTimePicker getStartDate();
        DateTimePicker getEndDate();
        ListBox getDisplayType();
        ListBox getProductList();
    }

    ...

    private void initializeCharts() {
        getProducts();

        ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
        chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                audiencePieChart = new PieChart();
                audienceLineChart = new LineChart();
                getView().getPageChartWrap().add(audiencePieChart);
                getView().getPageChartWrap().add(audienceLineChart);
                drawAudienceCharts();


                likeScatterChart = new ScatterChart();
                getView().getPageChartWrap().add(likeScatterChart);
                drawLikeCharts();

                likeScatterChartProduct = new ScatterChart();
                getView().getLikeScatterChartProductWrap().add(likeScatterChartProduct);
                drawLikeChartsForProduct();
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawAudienceCharts() {
         AudienceChartData data = getData();
         drawAudienceLineChart(data, PeriodType.Monthly)
         drawAudiencePieChart();
    }

    private void drawAudienceLineChart(AudienceChartData data, final PeriodType periodType) {

        int[][] values;     
        if (periodType == PeriodType.MONTHLY) {
            values = new int[][] { data.getMonthlyVisitors()};
        } 

        // Prepare the data
        DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Period");
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Visitors");

        log.info("Lengths: \n"  
                + "data.getPeriodLabels() : " + data.getPeriodLabels().length + "\n"
                + "data.getWeeklyVisitors() : " + data.getWeeklyVisitors().length + "\n"
                + "data.getWeeklyVisitorsNew() : " + data.getWeeklyVisitorsNew().length + "\n"
                + "data.getWeeklyVisitorsReturning() : " + data.getWeeklyVisitorsReturning().length + "\n");

        String [] periods = data.getPeriodLabels(); 
        dataTable.addRows(periods.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
            dataTable.setValue(i, 0, periods[i]);
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < values.length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < values[col].length; row++) {
                dataTable.setValue(row, col + 1, values[col][row]);
            }
        }

        // Set options
        LineChartOptions lineChartOptions = LineChartOptions.create();

        if (periodType == PeriodType.MONTHLY) {
            lineChartOptions.setTitle("Audience Overview: Monthly");
            lineChartOptions.setHAxis(HAxis.create("Month"));
        } 

        lineChartOptions.setVAxis(VAxis.create("Users"));

        // Draw the chart
        audienceLineChart.draw(dataTable, lineChartOptions);
    }

    private void drawAudiencePieChart(AudienceChartData data) {
        // Prepare the data
        DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Category");
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Number of users");

        dataTable.addRows(2);

        // Add data for returning visitors
        dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "Returning Visitor: " + data.getTotalVisitorsReturning());
        dataTable.setValue(0, 1, data.getTotalVisitorsReturning());

        // Add data for new visitors                
        dataTable.setValue(1, 0, "New Visitor: " + data.getTotalVisitorsNew());             
        dataTable.setValue(1, 1, data.getTotalVisitorsNew());

        // Set options
        PieChartOptions options = PieChartOptions.create();

        // options.setColors(colors);
        options.setIs3D(true);
        options.setTitle("Audience Overview (Total Visitors: " + data.getTotalVisitors() + ")");

        // Draw the chart
        audiencePieChart.draw(dataTable, options);
        audiencePieChart.addReadyHandler(new ReadyHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onReady(ReadyEvent event) {
                audiencePieChart.setSelection(Selection.create(1, null));
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawLikeCharts() {

        final PeriodType periodType = getView().getDisplayType().getSelectedIndex() == 0 ? PeriodType.MONTHLY : PeriodType.WEEKLY;

    reportingService.getLikesData(periodType, getView().getStartDate().getValue(), getView().getEndDate().getValue(), new AsyncCallback<LikesChartData>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            log.info("drawLikeCharts() onFailure()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LikesChartData data) {
            log.info("drawLikeCharts() onSuccess()");

            // Prepare the data
            DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();

            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Period");
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Likes");

            long[] likes = data.getLikes();
            String[] periods = data.getPeriodLabels();
            dataTable.addRows(data.getLikes().length);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.getLikes().length; ++i) {
                dataTable.setValue(i, 0, periods[i]);
                dataTable.setValue(i, 1, likes[i]);
            }

            // Set options
            ScatterChartOptions options = ScatterChartOptions.create();
            options.setTitle("Total Page Likes: " + data.getTotalLikes());
            options.setHAxis(HAxis.create("Periods"));
            options.setVAxis(VAxis.create("Number of Likes"));

            // Draw the chart
            likeScatterChart.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
    });
}

private void drawLikeChartsForProduct() {
    final PeriodType periodType = getView().getDisplayType().getSelectedIndex() == 0 ? PeriodType.MONTHLY : PeriodType.WEEKLY;

    int productId = Integer.parseInt(getView().getProductList().getSelectedValue());
    reportingService.getLikesData(productId, periodType, getView().getStartDate().getValue(), getView().getEndDate().getValue(), new AsyncCallback<LikesChartData>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            log.info("drawLikeChartsForProduct() onFailure()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LikesChartData data) {
            log.info("drawLikeChartsForProduct() onSuccess()");

            // Prepare the data
            DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();

            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Period");
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Likes");

            long[] likes = data.getLikes();
            String[] periods = data.getPeriodLabels();

            dataTable.addRows(data.getLikes().length);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.getLikes().length; ++i) {
                dataTable.setValue(i, 0, periods[i]);
                dataTable.setValue(i, 1, likes[i]);
            }

            // Set options
            ScatterChartOptions options = ScatterChartOptions.create();
            options.setTitle("Total Product Likes: " + data.getTotalLikes());
            options.setHAxis(HAxis.create("Periods"));
            options.setVAxis(VAxis.create("Number of Likes"));

            // Draw the chart
            likeScatterChartProduct.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify which are showing and which are not? because for example pie charts if empty will show blank whereas a line chart would still show the graph...

Comment: @YoussefLahoud, any of the charts randomly show. Sometimes, all of the charts show.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, try debugging the fetched data see what's happening after the data is fetched maybe an exception is escaping before calling the draw() method.

If everything is correct try the following:
After fetching the data, instead of calling

```
likeScatterChart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Try creating the graph object here and adding it to the wrapper after the rpc call for example:

```
       Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  PieChart pie =new PieChart(createTable(), createPieChartOptions()); 
                  pie.setSize("100%", "100%");

                  getView().getPageChartWrap().add(pie);
              }
        };

        VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
```

I hope this would help you.